# jQuery toggle only working for the top element in the <ul>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

I'm trying to implement the jQuery toggle item in my Rails 3.2.1 app.

I would like the toggle to work for each individual `<li>` item on the `<ul>`, so I can target which element to hide/show individually. But for some reason, only the top element has the toggle effect; the rest are not responding.

Here's [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/26/).

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `ID` must be unique per element... you cannot have 3 different elements with the ID `trigger`.. make them classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because your `div`s all have the same `id`, which is invalid HTML. Since the DOM is only expecting there to be one element with any given ID, then when you write `$("#trigger")`, it only selects the first one it finds. Change the ID to a class.

```html
<div class="trigger"> ...
```

And change your ID selector to a class selector.

```js
$('.trigger').click(/* ... */);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/zBeKG/)

Comment: More about the difference between IDs and classes: [a concise overview](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_idclass.htm); [a long explanation](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: thanks so much guys, really appreciate it! :) all answers are valid but i can only accept one. just picking the top one

Answer (score 0):

ID attributes must be unique on the page. Change all the id="trigger" to class="trigger" then try:

```
$(".trigger").click(function (){
     $(this).find('.menu-item').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/MsYdJ/28/)

```
$(".trigger").click('.menu-item', function () {
    $(".menu-item", this).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements with the same id is invalid HTML, and jQuery will only target the first that it finds with that id.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/27/) to use a class instead of ids

```
    <div id="trigger" class="trigger">
```

Then:

```
    $(".trigger").click(function (){
        $(".menu-item", this).toggle();
    });
```

to target the class and not the id.

Answer (score 0):

Why do the elements have the same `id`s? An ID should be unique. If you want to select all the `<li>`s, use a CSS selector like `$(".toggle-li")`.